# R custom function on a column and by list

Tags: r

I am trying to understand a piece of code in R and need to confirm my understanding.

The `df` has following variables: `signal`, `actualPos` and `neighbour`

The code is as follows:

```
res = df[,calculateDistance(signal), by=list(actualPos, neighbour)]
```

Does it mean that the data is first grouped by `actualPos` and `neighbour` and then the function `calculateDistance` is applied on `signal` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't base R, but `data.table` syntax, which you can confirm by reading the [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html). Your interpretation seems fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer